# eWordpress change image url by responsive breakpoint?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm searching a way to EASILY add responsive alternative images to content. For example I have three different images, one for each size (desktop, tablet and mobile) and would like to show them according to responsive breakpoints.

Foundation framework has "interchange" built in, but there is no easy way to add the images except by adding the code:

```
<img data-interchange="[/path/to/small-image.jpg, (small)], [/path/to/bigger-image.jpg, (large)]">
```

Anybody know any plugin that could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it like this. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWcDD.png) I used the Visual Composer plugin and made a simple add-on plugin that enables content editor to attach two different images. The plugin just writes these image tags and Foundation frameworks css hides and show them accordingly:

```
<img src="default.jpg" class="show-for-medium-up">
<img src="small.jpg" class="show-for-small-only">
```

I couldn't get Foundations Interchange images to work inside Visual Composer. Maybe it has something to do about javascript queue. Visual Composer content loads after foundation or something..

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all three images in the page and show every image for specific screen width;

```
<div>
    <img class="image-small" src="/path/to/small-image.jpg" /> 
    <img class="image-medium" src="/path/to/medium-image.jpg" /> 
    <img class="image-big" src="/path/to/big-image.jpg" /> 
</div>

.image-medium,
.image-small{
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
   .image-medium{
       display: inline;
   }

   .image-big{
       display: none;
   }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
   .image-small{
       display: inline;
   }

   .image-big{
       display: none;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that would require content editor to add CSS classes to image tags -> failure. Doesn't really differ from the Foundation Interchange method. I'm searching for a plugin, that could insert & edit small, medium, large images to content preferrably without clumsy shortcodes.

Comment: and what about  to add add_image_size( ) function in the function.php that will generate for you different sizes of image authomatically and you can insert all free images in the post

Comment: I need to have different images, not just sizes.

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest to use the Srcset attribute and then implement fallbacks (ex. [picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/)) for browsers you need to support.

by viewport

```
<img src="img-1x.jpg"
     srcset="img-1x.jpg 500w, img-2x.jpg 800w"
     alt="">
```

or by resolution

```
<img src="img-1x.jpg"
     srcset="img-1x.jpg 1x, img-2x.jpg 2x"
     alt="">
```

Comment: Sorry, this also needs HTML magician to get it right. What I'm looking for is a visual way to input image file names -> WP plugin.